# How to know when sending email is the email address is wrong?

Tags: apex, email

Its possible to know If an email address is wrong when send an email through apex? For example 'test@gmai. com'

Comment: if your email is wrong then you dont want to hit the exception ?

Answer (score 2):

The concept you're speaking of is called *validation*, which means ensuring that the input 'makes sense'. It's not possible to ever ensure that the input is true (the user may even have misspelled it), but it's making the best out of it.

Usually, this is achieved by using [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). However, the 'official' regular expression for an email is quite complicated. You can find some regular expressions for emails for different languages [here](http://emailregex.com/) (Apex not included!). You can even come up with your own.

Once you've found a regular expression that works for you, you can use the code posted by @Anjuna above, which uses regex validation in Apex.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the code below .It will help you to validate email in apex code.

```
 public static Boolean validateEmail(String email) {

        String emailRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'; 
        Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
        Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(email);

        return MyMatcher.matches()
        }
```

Comment: you can simply `return MyMatcher.matches()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can validate this as of now in Apex.You might have to use any app or something but in the standard way, its not possible.Below is an idea raised for the same at ideaExchange:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K0Gv

Answer (score 0):

Whatsoever validation rule is you cannot actually tell if the email id exists or not. "pranay32423423@gmail.com" does not exist but according to regular expression its a valid email id and it will send.

We don't have a standard Salesforce driven solution for this, but we can achieve this by using a third party API.

https://mailboxlayer.com/ is one such api that we have used in our project to find if the email id is valid or not. You can look at similar and some free ones if valid emails are need of your company.

Sync way: Make a callout and find out if email id is valid or not and then use Apex email.

or

Async way : Create a nightly batch to validate the email ids of contact or your object , thus whenever you send the email you are assured it will reach a valid recipient.